# How to handle a WEB API that has different responses types for success and failure?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, restsharp, webapi

I'm working on a WEB API application made with .NET Framework. Right now i'm working alonside a supplier to help and integrate their WEB API with our system. One of their latest change broke my code. Since i'm using RestSharp library i'm expecting the response to always correspond to a specific type of object, independently if with was a success or failure from their side.

`IRestResponse<T> response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync<T>(request);`

If the response is successful they will send a json response like this

`{message:"", jobNr:"2312312", status:"1"}`

And then they changed the code, so that if any request input was wrong they will send a list of errors, so the response will be like this:

`[{code:100, message:"contact phone is wrong"},{code:101, message:"the email is not provided"}]`

I don't like this approach, since i think they should give a response for errors like this:

`{errorMessages:[{code:100, message:"contact phone is wrong"},{code:101, message:"the email is not provided"}]}`

But since it is not in my hands. How should i deal with it? Just parse the json response and assing to different types of objects? Thanks.

Comment: Firstly dont use RestSharp for this exact reason, use HttpClient where you have more fine grained control over reading the status codes and deserializing, you can also include the error/error array in your DTO, the serializer wont care so much... However, the wild west doesn't stop here, I have seen examples of api resources returning many different schemas on the same status code (untyped languages have a lot to answer for, \*looking at you javascript\*)... However, in summary, don't use RestSharp to start with, its well and truly past its used by date

Comment: Does Response's status code change on error? (Like turning into 400 from 200)

Comment: @A.Mokhtari yes they send the status code 400.

Comment: @TheGeneral you may be right, RestSharp seems like a nice library to use, but actually i bet there is a lot better like HttpClient. But APIs that return different schemas just seems wrong to me. Anyway in this case, i manneged to convice them to apply the schema for errors i have on my post.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, the response should be parsed manually.

Assuming **RestSharp** is still in charge and the original API returns errors entitled with `BadRequest` status code, below extension tries to deserialize the content as an array of errors (a type consists of a code and a message just like mentioned in question).

```
    public static Error[] AsErrors(this IRestResponse response)
    {
        var empty = new Error[] { };
        try
        {
            return response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
                    ? JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Error[]>(response.Content)
                    : empty;
        }
        catch (JsonException)
        {
            return empty;
        }
    }
```

Considering the `NormalContent` is what you truly expect as response, the usage will be:

```
    // after creating client and request ...
    var response = client.Execute<NormalContent>(request);
    var errors = response.AsErrors();
    if (errors.Any())
    {
            //Deal with errors
    }
    else
    {
            //response.Data gets populated with RealResult
    }
```

**NOTE:** Using the procedure as an extension depends on how common is the response pattern in your case.